# How to clear web cache in iOS

Tags: ios, caching

I tried the following way:

```
  [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
```

It clears the cache.db but it is still in memory. 
It does not delete it permanently.

I am able to read it through "strings"

Does anybody know how to purge cache.db in iOS(pragmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried this, but still I am able to read cache.db from memory through strings commands. My Requirement is 1. In app , I want to enable cache and want url responses to be saved in cache.db. 2 Before logout, I want to clear web cache permanently, It should not be recoverable through strings.